# Socket Programming in visual studio with C++

Tags: c++, sockets, ip, bind, listen

I write a program for chat, but when i run server side,it produce error in listen function. i don't know what's the causes error!
by the way, how i must run that?first server then client?what about IP address? how i set them? i want to run it just on the same PC.
`

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <winsock2.h>
    #include <Ws2tcpip.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "iostream"
    #include "conio.h"
    using namespace std;
   #pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
   #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
   #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
   #define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

int main()
{

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = 0;            
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char *sendbuf = "Server: sending data test";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";


SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;


sockaddr_in service;


iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
    cout<<"Error at WSAStartup()\n";

}

ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    cout<<"socket function failed with error: %u\n"<< WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
    getch();

}

service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.52");
service.sin_port = htons(27015);

iResult = bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR *) &service, sizeof (service));
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout<<"bind failed with error \n"<< WSAGetLastError();
    getch();
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();

}
else{

    wprintf(L"bind returned success\n");
    WSACleanup();
    getch();
}

if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR){
    cout<<"listen function failed with error: "<< WSAGetLastError();
    iResult = closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    getch();
}



cout<<"Waiting for client to connect...\n";

ListenSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    cout<<"accept failed with error: \n"<< WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    getch();
} else
    cout<<"Client connected.\n";

iResult = send( ListenSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout<<"send failed with error: "<< WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    getch();
    WSACleanup();

}else
    cout<<"Bytes Sent: "<< iResult;


do {

    iResult = recv(ListenSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( iResult > 0 )
        cout<<"Bytes received: "<< iResult;   
    else if ( iResult == 0 ){
        cout<<"Connection closed";   
    getch();}
    else{
        cout<<"recv failed with error: "<< WSAGetLastError();
       getch();
    }
} while( iResult > 0 );


iResult = closesocket(ListenSocket);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout<<"close failed with error: \n"<< WSAGetLastError();
    WSACleanup();
    getch();
}


return 0;
    }
```

`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
 #define DEFAULT_PORT 27015

int main() {

int Result;
WSADATA wsaData;

SOCKET SocketNumber = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct sockaddr_in clientService; 

int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
char *sendbuf = "Client: sending data test";
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN] = "";

Result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (Result != NO_ERROR) {
    cout<<"WSAStartup failed with error: "<< Result;
    getch();
}

SocketNumber = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (SocketNumber == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    cout<<"socket failed with error: "<< WSAGetLastError();
       getch();
    WSACleanup();
}

clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "127.0.0.1" );
clientService.sin_port = htons( DEFAULT_PORT );

Result = connect( SocketNumber, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof(clientService) );
if (Result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout<<"connect failed with error: "<< WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(SocketNumber);
    getch();
    WSACleanup();

 }
Result = send( SocketNumber, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
if (Result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout<<"send failed with error: "<< WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(SocketNumber);
    getch();
    WSACleanup();

}

cout<<"Bytes Sent: "<< Result;

Result = shutdown(SocketNumber, SD_SEND);
if (Result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    cout<<"shutdown failed with error: "<< WSAGetLastError();
    closesocket(SocketNumber);
       getch();
    WSACleanup();

}
do {

    Result = recv(SocketNumber, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if ( Result > 0 )
        cout<<"Bytes received: "<< Result;   
    else if ( Result == 0 )
        cout<<"Connection closed";   
    else
        cout<<"recv failed with error: "<< WSAGetLastError();
       getch();
} while( Result > 0 );


Result = closesocket(SocketNumber);
if (Result == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    wprintf(L"close failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
       getch();
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "*it produce error in listen function*" What is the error? Also, the server should probably `bind` to "0.0.0.0".

Comment: add error to question for answer to your Question faster!

Comment: error message is:listen function failed with error :10093

Comment: change: `inet_addr("192.168.1.52");` to `inet_addr("localhost");`

Answer (score 3):

delete two lines after " wprintf(L"bind returned success\n");" in server, i mean these lines:

```
WSACleanup();
getch();
```

and it will be ok!